# Write data to TXT file

Tags: php, arrays, fwrite

I need to write some data into the txt file to be able to open it in MS Excel and get each value in a separate cell. How to do this?

```
$file = "outputs.txt";
$handle = fopen($file, 'w');
$data = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $gener; $i++) {
      $data = $data + $i + "; ";
      for ($j = 0; $j < $size; $j++)
      {
        $data = $data + $set->getEntry($j)->getValue(0) + 
                ", " + $set->getEntry($j)->getValue(1) + "; ";
      }
      $data = $data + "\n";
      fwrite($handle, $data); 
}
```

Comment: Either write an .xls file using a library made for that purpose, or generate a .csv file using tools made for this purpose, which Excel will accept as well. Google both, there are plenty of questions, examples and code out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would generate a .csv file and then open it with excel.

You can generate it using this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php and then  you can open the .csv file in excel.